# iOS Referencing Outlet Collections

Tags: ios, outlet

I've created a new Long Press Geasture on linked it to a Action with corrisponding function but it doesn't have a Referncing Outlet Collection so therefore isn't firing.

Seems stupid, but how do you add a Referencing Outlet Collection in Xcode 4.3?

Comment: There isn't relevant code. It's Storyboard mode in Xcode 4.3

Comment: Figured it out. Just drag the relevant item from the list and drop it on relevant view

Comment: hey good.. self study huh.. :)